# Sweatalert submit confirmacion funciona solo en un boton

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

estoy trabajando con eliminación de registros en laravel, estoy implementando una alerta de sweatalert para que cuando se le de clic al botón de eliminar pida confirmación de eliminación o cancelación de la acción, pero me doy cuenta que funciona con solo un registro, con los otros hace el submit del form sin lanzar la ventana de confirmacion...

El script de la ventana para pedir la confirmacion lo tengo asi:

```
<script>


            $("#form-eliminar").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    Swal.fire({

                    title: 'Esta Seguro de Eliminar la Imagen?',
                    text: "Los cambios son irreversibles!",
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Si, eliminar!',
                    cancelButtonText: 'No eliminar!',
                    }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                       /*  swal(
                        'Deleted!',
                        'Your file has been deleted.',
                        'success'
                        ) */
                        this.submit();
                    }
                    });
                });


    </script>
```

y cuando se confirma la eliminacion, lanzo otra alerta con un mensaje de confirmacion:

```
 @if(Session::has('eliminar') == "ok")
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                  /*  Swal.fire(
                        'Imagen Eliminada!',
                        'La imagen fue Eliminada y Borrada de la Base de Datos',
                        'success'
                        ) */
                        swal("IMAGEN ELIMINADA!", "La imagen fue Eliminada y Borrada de la Base de Datos", "success",{
    icon: 'success',

    showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1900


  })
                </script>
            @endif
```

y la funcion del controlador:

```
 public function destroy( $id){
        $imagen = ImagenesMantenimiento::where('id', $id)->first();

        $url =str_replace('storage','public',$imagen->ruta);

        //Elimina la imagen fisicamente
        Storage::delete($url);

        //Elimina de la tabla
        $imagen->delete();

        //return redirect()->to(route('mantenimientos.ejecuciones.show', $imagen->imageable_id));
        return redirect()->to(route('mantenimiento.editar.ejecucion', $imagen->imageable_id))->with('eliminar', 'ok');



    }
```

COn un registro lanza la ventana de confirmacion sin problemas, con los otros hace el submit y elimina de forma directa y solo muestra la alerta de registro eliminado....

Saludos a todos

Comment: Hola Nicolas. Que datos estas enviado desde tu controlador?

Comment: Hola cristian, edite la pregunta añadiendo la funcion que tengo en el controlador, basicamente es el codigo para eliminar una imagen y que al hacer el delete me redireccione a la misma vista

Comment: En el controlador puedes cambiar el destroy($id) por destroy(ImagenesMantenimiento $imagen) y en la ruta que se encuentra en web.php pasar la variable de esta manera '/tu-url/{imagen}'. De esta manera no debes hacer nuevamente una consulta a la base de datos.

Comment: En tu controlador no veo que generes el session para que luego en el blade lo valides o generas el session en otro sitio?

Comment: Es un formulario que elimina una imagen o varias imágenes con diferentes formularios?

Comment: hola cristian, se eliminan una o varias imagenes

Comment: Si son varias imagenes, entiendo que hay un formulario por imagen cierto? Si es asi, cuando manejas el formulario mediante JQuery, estas manejando un unico formulario.